# how to continue bubble sorting

Tags: python, sorting

```
def bubble(v):
l = len(v)
for i in range(l-1):
    for j in range(l-i-1):
        if v[j]>v[j+1]:
            v[j+1],v[j] = v[j],v[j+1]
    return v
```

If I try bubble([5,4,3,2,1]) it prints 43215 I want the code to continue comparing where should I fix?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you just need to fix the indentation of your return. Trying putting it at the same level of the first for loop; otherwise, you will return the result (and therefore exit from your function) at the first iteration of your external loop.

Comment: Really it's everything between the `def` and the `return` that is wrong - needs more indentation.

Comment: Yep, I agree, but I assumed that that was just a typo, because otherwise the code would not have shown the behaviour that Strawberry described. But, of course, you are totally right: all the lines beside the first and the last one should be indented one level more

Answer (score 0):

`return` should be tabbed left. If you put it here it stops execution after the first iteration (of the first for-loop).

```
def bubble(v):
    l = len(v)
    for i in range(l-1):
        for j in range(l-i-1):
            if v[j]>v[j+1]:
                v[j+1],v[j] = v[j],v[j+1]
    return v
```